# Is there an server explorer for Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How can I use Visual Studio server explorer on my Mac there is no option like that.I have tried to use Rider but I couldn't manage it. Pleasee  help

Comment: Azure data studio is a cross platform alternative - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft have no plans to include this featue in Visual studio for Mac: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/371069/sql-object-explorer-visual-studio-for-mac.html

And they recommend you use Azure Data Studio:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/azure-data-studio/what-is-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver15

I believe there is also a extension for vscode which is similar